# g++ how to wrap open syscall when using ofstream

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I want to wrap all open syscalls, it works ok when I am opening file by

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

This call jumps to wrapper function, but when I am using C++ file functions it doesnot work - wrap function not called.

```
ofstream test_file(file_path_str);
```

Anyway ofstream test_file(file_path_str) should ends with open syscall.

Linker flags are: -Wl,wrap,open

Update:

Ok I post a simple example:

file main.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream test_file ("file1");
  int fd = open("file2", O_NONBLOCK | O_RDWR, 0666);

  return 0;
}
```

file wrapper.cc

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" int __real_open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);

extern "C" int __wrap_open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode) {

    printf("Under __wrap_open, open file: %s\n", pathname);

    return __real_open(pathname, flags, mode);
}
```

Then build and start program:

```
g++ -c main.cc
g++ -c wrapper.cc
g++ -Wl,wrap,open main.o wrapper.o -o test
./test
Under __wrap_open, open file: file2
```

Can be seen that only open("file2"... was wrapped but no ofstream. Why ?...

Comment: You could use `LD_PRELOAD` tricks

Comment: With preload the same, only C open wrapped but not open from ofstream